# SASS/CSS: :first-child selector not working

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I'm trying to style a certain `<div>` in my markup with CSS/SASS, and I'm clueless as to why it's not applying the rules. This is my markup:

```
<div class="row addon-header">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    // something here
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <h6><em>Slogan</em></h6>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            // I want to access this
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the SASS I'm trying to use for it:

```
div.addon-header {
    color: white;
    > div.col-sm-9 > div.col-xs-1:first-child {
        background-color: black;
        padding-left: 0px !important;
    }
}
```

If I remove the `:first-child` selector in my SASS, it's working, but obvious for every `<div class="col-xs-1">` not just the first one, which is not what I want.

I also tried playing around and doing something like

```
div.addon-header {
    color: white;
    > div.col-sm-9 > div.col-xs-1 {
        &:first-child {
            background-color: black;
            padding-left: 0px !important;
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
div.addon-header {
    color: white;
    > div.col-sm-9 {
        > div.col-xs-1:first-child {
            background-color: black;
            padding-left: 0px !important;
        }
    }
}
```

or using `:nth-child(1)` instead. Nothing works. I'm clueless. Somewhere else in my SASS, I have the following:

```
.tab-content {
    >.tab-pane:first-child > form > div.row > div {
        // rules here
        > div.picture-container {
            // rules here
        }
    }
    >.tab-pane {
        // rules here
    }
    >.tab-pane:nth-child(4) > form {
        // rules here
    }
}
```

Which is working just fine. So I really don't get what I'm doing wrong in the first example. Anyone able to help?

Comment: This is due to the way the `first-child` selector works, the `div` isn't the `first-child` the `h2` is. https://jsfiddle.net/qb2d66d4/1/

Comment: Thanks to @arturmoroz and everyone else, I figured it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`col-xs-1` need to wrap `row` because this block is not first element. First element is `h2`

Answer (score 1):

You need the [`:nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) (or, in your case, the [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) selector).

In the example your provided the `:first-child` of `.col-sm-9` element is the `h2`.

```
div.addon-header {
    color: white;
    > div.col-sm-9 > div.col-xs-1:first-of-type {
        background-color: black;
        padding-left: 0px !important;
    }
}
```

Note, though, that the `:nth-of-type()` selectors, like the `:nth-child()` selectors, apply to tags only, not class names; if you were to insert another `div` before the first `.col-xs-1` then this would no longer work.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using @arturmoroz answer, because wrapping the cols in a row negates the need for `padding-left: 0px` altogether, so I save some CSS. But your answer worked as well.